# Android TextInputLayout is not showing error

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, textinputlayout

I am using EditText with TextInputLayout. This is the code, that I am using to display error.

```
  private boolean validateEmail() {
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
        inputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(true);
        inputLayoutEmail.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_email));
        requestFocus(inputEmail);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I am calling this method in edittext's textwatcher like in this link http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-floating-labels-for-edittext/

Once I entered a valid input then clear that ,it will show error message as expected,But it wont work if i enter the text again and then clear it again.ie.It is not showing any error message.

I am using `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'` library.

```
inputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(true);
```

is calling but error is not displaying. What might be the problem? How I can solve this?

Comment: Change requestFocus(inputEmail); -> inputEmail.requestFocus();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example worked for me.

you use

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

and the right one is

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Comment: it is working in first time.Second time onwards it is not showing error.but getting focus.

Comment: ok. I got it - you use compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0' and the right one is compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

Comment: thanks..It works with com.android.support:design:23.0.1

Comment: Can you please add this in your answer.So that I can accept your answer

Comment: what about if my compile sdk version  will 24 ?

Answer (score 49):

In your layout file, ensure you have `layout_height="wrap_content"` for the TextInputLayout 
 instead of a dimension. This was causing the issue for me.

Comment: Solved my issue after 4hours of investigation in all classes..thanks

Comment: @mg3, glad I could help. I spent more time than I'd like to admit to on this and didn't see this solution posted anywhere else, so I figured someone else may benefit!

Comment: seems to actually be the layout_height more specifically - and it doesn't need to be set to wrap_content as such - just needs to be big enough -  but yes thanks I couldn't find this anywhere either !!

Comment: @philthomas26 from the answer and from your comment, I got this idea it is actually related to height, it is now working,thanks

Comment: you are the best!

Comment: @aaronvargas Thank you for an AWESOME answer, i also lost around 4 hours same as LearningPath, why don't google mention this type of issues properly..

Answer (score 7):

You just need apply,

```
inputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
inputLayoutEmail.setError(null);
```

It worked for me. Hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue and i was using data binding so adding below line solved my issue : 
 app:errorEnabled="true"

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Support Library, revision 23.4.0 (May 2016)

Fixed an issue where `TextInputLayout` doesn't clear error tint after `setErrorEnabled(false)` on API level 21 - 22 [(Issue 202829)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202829)

Comment: This issue does not seem to be fixed in 23.4.0.